# Dropzone.- Change the name of a previewed photo element

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

Im in the last step of setting dropzone along with another input fields. Now Im in the process of giving the uploaded previewd image the new name from the server response, but accordingly [#244](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/244) I have to

```
myDropzone.on("success", function(file, response) {
    file.previewElement.find('[data-dz-name]').html(response.title);
});
```

but its not working (I have the response variable set with the name)
my html is

```
        <p class="name" data-dz-name>images.jpeg</p>
        <strong class="error text-danger" data-dz-errormessage=""></strong>
```

what is wrong with my javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasnt fetching correctly the response from server at the "response" variable